# Parsing issue with Low Variable - Playa field (EE 2.11.9)

Tags: playa, low-variables, parse-order, embeds

Obscure issue for you here.

I have a Low Variable (using Playa) that contains several entries. I need to pass the entry_id for each entry to an embedded file. When I do this, the embed loads, but the {exp:channel:entries...} tag does not work.

```
  {exp:low_variables:pair var="newsletter_sidebars"}
    {embed="inc/get-sidebars-by-entry_id" the_entry_id="{entry_id}"}
  {/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

If I pass a number directly to my embed:

```
{embed="inc/get-sidebars-by-entry_id" the_entry_id="12"}
```

It works fine.

I can even see my embed is receiving the value of the Playa field.

Something to do with the dreaded parse order?

Comment: Dreaded parse order, I think so. If embed tags allowed `parse="inward"` you'd be OK, but I don't think they do. But also, `{entry_id}` is a, well, a namespace problem in many templates. What happens if you output (in plain text) `{entry_id}` in the low_var loop but not in the embed? Does it render?

Comment: @jrothafer Outputting {entry_id} in plain text in the low_var loop does output the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the var param in the variable you are trying to output?

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="newsletter_sidebars"}
    {embed="inc/get-sidebars-by-entry_id" the_entry_id="{newsletter_sidebars:entry_id}"}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same embed effect but with greater control over parse order by using the [embed function of `{stash}`](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Embeds).

Comment: Thanks @jcogs.eecms. The Stash documentation is a bit confusing. Can you suggest a quick way to accomplish this?